# Reading Request Payload in PHP

Tags: php, post, request, payload

How can I read content of Request Payload (POST) using PHP?

I´m using a Angular aplication to send the POST.

I've tried with: `$_POST`, `$_FILES` and `file_get_contents('php://input')` ...

None worked.

Comment: Please insert your code into the question (both front-end and back-end)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need view x-www-form-urlencoded post data, just use

```
print_r($_POST);
```

If you need view json post data, use this

```
$data=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),1);
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
```